# How get a parameter from url

Tags: javascript

Suppose to have this url:

```
var url = data.url (data is an object with url e other fields)
```

So the url, after a console, is:

```
/user/prova8/edit/username
```

In the url `"prova8"` is the username and I must use it. Anyone can explain me how I can get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JavaScript **[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method

```js
var url = '/user/prova8/edit/username';

console.log(
  url.split('/')[2]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string_user="/user/prova8/edit/username";
array_user=string_user.split("/");
alert("The user is: "+array_user[2])
```